# Check if directory exists, make directory

Tags: php

I'm having a little trouble with this. Thought it'd be easier, but turning out to frustrate. All I'm trying to do is have a text field where I can type the name of a new directory, check if that directory exists, and if not create it. I have found about 50 other people with almost the exact same code, so thought I had it correct but I keep getting Directory exists as per the "if" statement.

Eventually I want to tie this into my file upload script.

Here is the insert.php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="directory">Directory:</label>
    <input value="<?php if ($_POST && $errors) {
  echo htmlentities($_POST['directory'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
}?>" type="text" name="directory" id="directory" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="insert" />
  </p>
</form>
```

And here is the post.php

```
try {
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $directory = $_POST['directory'];
    $photo_destination = 'image_upload/';
    $path = $photo_destination;
    $new_path = $path . $directory;
    $mode = 0755;
    if(!is_dir($new_path)) {
        echo "The Directory {$new_path} exists";
        } else {
            mkdir($new_path , 0777);
            echo "The Directory {$new_path} was created";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `/scripts` directory on your system? That seems like a mistake.

Comment: Please provide output of `ls -lh /scripts`

Comment: Do you really need exist/created message? If not just go ahead and try to create it WITHOUT checking if it exists or not. 1 syscall vs. 2 and you're guaranteed to create directory even in rare race condition case when it is removed just after you've checked it exists.

Comment: @tadman yes that was a mistake, but still not the problem.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov yes I want it to tell me if it exists already, as this will be growing rapidly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change this :

```
if(!is_dir($new_path)) {
    echo "The Directory {$new_path} exists";
    }
```

to this :

```
if(is_dir($new_path)) {
    echo "The Directory {$new_path} exists";
    }
```

Try and tell me the result :)

Comment: Now I get the message "The Directory was created" but still not creating the directory. This is on a windows system, do I need to start all the way at the driver letter C:/ or does it make directory starting from where the script is ran?

Comment: You are using the "/" character in the start of your path and that tell the server that it must start from the root of your server then compute the path by this way i think your folder is created but not where you want but in the server root directory under the folder "/scripts/image_upload/" so if you want the script take computing of the path from the directory that the script is running just omit the / from the start of your path and you will tell the server in this way that the path i am pointing to is beside the file script that run this folder creation @tunedin

Comment: Ok figured that portion out! Thanks for the correct answer. Simple mistake

Comment: For nothing ! and don't hesitate to ask me every time what you need and i will give you my full help soon as possible when i get your question :)

Comment: Don't forget to check the result of your `mkdir` call, as that might fail for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `is_dir` in the if block you can use `file_exists`. Because  file_exists is the function to check whether file exists or not. For the same you can also refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Proper way to check existence of file and directory is only by file_exists function. Good to know

Comment: No I dont want to check wether the file exists yet, though I know you can use it for directories as well. All I want to do here is create the directory, since it will be a new directory everytime no files will exist in it, so its a half full half empty situation

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if( is_dir( $new_path ) ) {
    echo "The Directory {$new_path} exists";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let someone wants to create a sub-folder,
with a year name under **`/uploads`** folder
then he/she want to create
another sub-folder under an **`/uploads/<year_name_folder>/`**,
named **`project_number`**.

```
$yearfolder = date('y');
if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$yearfolder)) {
        mkdir("uploads/".$yearfolder);
    }
*// Folder named by year has been created.*

$project_number = Any Unique field ,Come from database or anywhere !
$target_directory = mkdir("uploads/".$yearfolder."/".$project_number);

*// project number wise folder also created.
// If project number is not unique do check like year folder. I think every project number is unique.* 

$target_dir = "uploads/$yearfolder/$project_number/";
*//my target dir has created where my document or pic whatever will be uploaded.*

Now Upload ! Woo 
$target_file = $target_dir.($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```